# I am trying run selenium program on eclipse but i structed here .....it showing like this

Tags: java, selenium

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:199)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:109)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$100(GeckoDriverService.java:38)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(GeckoDriverService.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:296)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.createCommandExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:245)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:220)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:215)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:124)
    at automationFramework.FirstTestCase1.main(FirstTestCase1.java:11)
```

Comment: Did you set the webdriver.gecko.driver system property?

Answer (score 0):

you need to set up system variable.

add this before the driver call
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "path of downloaded file");

file can be downloaded from this
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases